# How to exclude error log level in a file logback spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

I have a spring boot app(spring-boot-starter-parent --> 2.3.0.RELEASE) that I am implementing log.

Basically what I am trying to achieve is that I have 2 log files one bridgeError.log which contains only error messages and bridge.log which will contain all log level **except** **Error level** since it is being logged in brideError.log file.

I am able to create 2 logs file brideError.log which contains only error messages but the issue is that
bridge.log also contains error messages.

Please find my logback-spring.xml configuration below:

```
<configuration>

    <property name="HOME_LOG" value="logs/bridge.log"/>
    <property name="HOME_LOG_ERROR" value="logs/bridgeError.log"/>


    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type
             ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE-ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${HOME_LOG}</file>

        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>DEBUG</level>
        </filter>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>logs/archived/bridge.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <!-- each archived file, size max 10MB -->
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            <!-- total size of all archive files, if total size > 20GB, it will delete old archived file -->
            <totalSizeCap>20GB</totalSizeCap>
            <!-- 60 days to keep -->
            <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>


    <appender name="FILE-ROLLING-ERROR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${HOME_LOG_ERROR}</file>

        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>ERROR</level>
        </filter>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>logs/archived/bridgeError.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <!-- each archived file, size max 10MB -->
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            <!-- total size of all archive files, if total size > 20GB, it will delete old archived file -->
            <totalSizeCap>20GB</totalSizeCap>
            <!-- 60 days to keep -->
            <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>
  
        <logger name="com.dummy.package" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <!--        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>-->
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </logger>


    <!--    <root level="error">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
            &lt;!&ndash;  <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>&ndash;&gt;
        </root>-->

    <logger name="com.dummy.package" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING-ERROR"/>
    </logger>

</configuration>
```

Is it possible to exclude error messages in bridge.log file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a level filter for that purpose

```
<filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
  <level>ERROR</level>
  <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
  <onMismatch>ACCEPT</onMismatch>
</filter>
```

Docs: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html